# To say "Lost paradise" or "paradise lost"?

Tags: difference, american-english, word-order, british-english

I don't have any specific context to work with but a thought came to mind as an English learner I stated to imagine if there would be any difference in both:

1 "lost paradise"

2 "paradise lost"

is the second option a more petic one only? or are there any different implication?

Comment: There *is* a context that might come to the mind of a native English speaker: the epic poem [*Paradise Lost*](https://www.bl.uk/works/paradise-lost) by John Milton, which is about so much more than just losing a paradise. Your first example "lost paradise" suggests, perhaps, a hidden valley that is rediscovered, or its location forgotten.

Comment: "paradise lost" is widely used, but that order is only used with paradise and maybe a few other relevant nouns, and exists because people have heard of Milton's poem and its title has become a common phrase. In general it's usual to talk about a "lost world", "lost life", "lost keys", "lost change", etc, putting "lost" first with other nouns. I don't know how often you talk about paradise, or in what context: it's mentioned in elevated literary contexts, not something you say down the pub.

Comment: If you don't have a specfic context, this question is probably unanswerable. We would need to know, from the context, if you are making an allusion to the poem.

Answer (score 1):

"Lost paradise" is referring to the site itself, as in "*Visiting Shangri-La  was like discovering a lost paradise.*", often with the site no longer being lost.

"Paradise lost" is referring to the effect on people and the future, as in "*The destruction of [famous site] is a paradise lost*" (a paradise that has been lost to us forever).